# How to resolve JSON Decode error having both single and double quotes in string?

Tags: python

All,

I'm getting the error when executing the below code. I'm using both single and double quotes escape characters in a JSON string value.

```
import json
jsondata = '{"Jobid":"12345","Desc":"84\" x 53\' material"}'
dumpJsonData = json.loads(jsondata)
print(dumpJsonData)
```

Could anyone have a solution for this?
Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the error? BTW: Did you `print(jsondata)`? Point is, that string is not JSON and that should become obvious if you printed it!

Comment: `jsondata = r'...'` — Use a raw string literal to have to worry less about escaping backslashes. This should be a non-issue in practice, since you're probably not reading your JSON from a string literal, but from some file, where you don't need to consider escaping a string correctly as Python source code literal.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a dictionary, packing the values with triple-quotes `"""` or joining `'"' + "'"`, before using `json.dumps()` to stringifiy it

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({"Jobid": "12345", "Desc": """84" x 53' material"""})
'{"Jobid": "12345", "Desc": "84\\" x 53\' material"}'
```

Comment: anytime! if this or other Answers solve your Question, please mark them with the check to the left to help yourself and the community - very simple, but official guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers